# creating custom statusbar in blackberry java

Tags: java, blackberry

[image]

this is the code i have tried so far i need to get view as shown in above fig.but in my code all images are grouped in left side and if i add background color or backgroundimage icon nothing will be visible expect backgroundcolor what mistake i have done please help me i am new to bb

```
 HorizontalFieldManager statusbar = new HorizontalFieldManager( );
/*  {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
        g.clear();
    }
    };*/
    VerticalFieldManager profvfm = new VerticalFieldManager();  

Bitmap msg3 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("emailicon.png");
BitmapField bitmapField2 = new BitmapField(msg3);
profvfm.add(bitmapField2);
LabelField prolbl = new LabelField("My Profile", LabelField.FOCUSABLE)
{
    protected void paintBackground(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics g)
    {
        g.clear();
        g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       // g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
       // g.setColor(Color.BLUE);               
    }
};  

FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 21);
prolbl.setFont(font);
profvfm.add(prolbl);
statusbar.add(profvfm);
VerticalFieldManager emlvfm = new VerticalFieldManager();   
Bitmap msg5 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("emailicon.png");
BitmapField bitmapField5 = new BitmapField(msg5);
emlvfm.add(bitmapField5);
LabelField emllbl = new LabelField("Inbox", LabelField.FOCUSABLE)
{
    protected void paintBackground(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics g)
    {
        g.clear();
        g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       // g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
       // g.setColor(Color.BLUE);               
    }
};  

// FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
Font font1 = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 28);
emllbl.setFont(font1);
emlvfm.add(emllbl); 
statusbar.add(emlvfm);

VerticalFieldManager socialvfm = new VerticalFieldManager();    
Bitmap msg4 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("emailicon.png");
BitmapField bitmapField3 = new BitmapField(msg4);
socialvfm.add(bitmapField3);
LabelField scllbl = new LabelField("Social", LabelField.FOCUSABLE)
{
protected void paintBackground(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics g)
{
    g.clear();
    g.getColor();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  // g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
  // g.setColor(Color.BLUE);               
}
};  

// FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
Font font2 = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 28);
scllbl.setFont(font2);
socialvfm.add(scllbl); 
 statusbar.add(socialvfm);
setStatus(statusbar);
```

and how to set font of label so that i could get look as in image

Comment: out of curiosity, can you remove items as well as add them?  Pare down the user experience?

Comment: @Thufir i didnt get about which items you are talking about please make your question clear.

Comment: can you enable/disable social, profile, etc?  Or, those are parts of the OS you can't touch with Java?

Comment: yes, you can enable and disable items